# Cut string in python by counting characters

Tags: python, string, cut

So I have a string inside of a file:
C:\d\folder\project\folder\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Module.c

What would be the best way to cut it just by counting backslashes from the end:
So in this case we need to cut everything what is after 4th backslash when counting backward:

Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Module.c

I need something to do this since I always need to count backward cause I know that in my folder structure it will be like that, I cannot count from the 1st character since number of backslashes "" will not always be the same when counting from the start.

Comment: Why is there a replace tag?

Comment: Cause at the moment first thing I tried is:for file in directory:
    open_file = open(file, 'r')
    change_file =  open_file.read()
    change_file = change_file.replace(here do something)

Comment: But I now I get it that it won't work like that

Answer (score 2):

If your string is always a path, you should be using `pathlib.Path` to handle it:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r'C:\d\folder\project\folder\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Module.c')
```

Then we can get the following:

```
>>> path.parts[-4:]
('Folder1', 'Folder2', 'Folder3', 'Module.c')
>>> os.sep.join(path.parts[-4:])
'Folder1\\Folder2\\Folder3\\Module.c'
```

Comment: I think John meant a string inside of the file.

Comment: Yeah exactly, string is inside of a file, so I have to do: for file in directory:

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
'\\'.join(s.split('\\')[-4:])
```

to read your file mentioned in comment:

```
with open('yourfile') as f:
    for s in f: # usually better than for s in f.readlines()
        print('\\'.join(s.split('\\')[-4:]))
```

readlines() loads all file into memory, can be problematic if the file is huge and exceeds process memory limits.

Comment: Current problem is that I have to read an inputs from a file with readlines() and I get an error that object list has no split command

Comment: readlines() method of stream return a list of lines  from the stream (your file). List elements are strings, each has split() method.

Comment: I understand! Thanks man, so I wrote it like this:  for file in directory:
    with open (file) as f:
        for s in f:
            print('\\'.join(s.split('\\')[-4:]))

Comment: Just have to figure out how to handle when file is empty, reports that file does not exist :(

Comment: Managed to fix it, but this does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

s = r'C:\d\folder\project\folder\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Module.c'

'\'.join(s.split('\')[:-4])

First the string is split based on the backslashes and all components excluding the last 4 are taken. These are then joined back using the backslash.

Comment: I am trying to test it out based on my code, so first I have to readlines from file as s and then place only this line?

Comment: Current problem is that with readlines(), I get an error that object list has no split command